# Шифрование файла xml

Tags: c#, xml

Добрый день. Как можно реализовать шифрование свойств при сериализации объекта. Например:

Из этого:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>
    <settings1>123</settings1>
    <settings2>567</settings2>
  </Data>
</AppParameters>
```

Получить:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>
    sadasd1ds1dsadasdfgsfgsd /*зашифрованные данные всех полей класса Data*/
  </Data>
</AppParameters>
```

Comment: Пока будете ждать ответы, могу посоветовать почитать про дотфускаторы

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это всё ещё сериализация? Возьмите тогда уж весь файл да зашифруйте любым алгоритмом.

Comment: @Monk, возможно есть методы шифрования свойств объекта при его сериализации, если нет, то соглашусь, логичнее использовать шифрование всего файла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хочется зашифровать файл, но оставить его текстовым/xml - то стоит посмотреть в сторону класса [`System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.decryptdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Он позволяет шифровать отдельные элементы (с использованием `RSA` или любого `SymmetricAlgorithm`) + умеет расшифровывать весь файл целиком:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Temp\in.xml");
    Encrypt(Create3DES("MyPasswword"), xmlDoc);

    xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Temp\enc.xml");

    Decrypt(Create3DES("MyPasswword"), xmlDoc);
    xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Temp\dec.xml");
}

private static TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Create3DES(string password)
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider encKey = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    encKey.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
    return encKey;
}

private static void Decrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm key, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);

    encryptedXml.AddKeyNameMapping("MyKey", key);

    encryptedXml.DecryptDocument();
}

private static void Encrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm key, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);

    var inputElement = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Data");

    encryptedXml.AddKeyNameMapping("MyKey", key);
    var ed = encryptedXml.Encrypt(inputElement, "MyKey");

    EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(inputElement, ed, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что лучше всего будет полностью зашифровать файл. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965042/c-sharp-serializing-deserializing-a-des-encrypted-file-from-a-stream)